# Ansible execute each role in different host

Tags: ansible

My intention is to execute each role in a different host. I am doing a simple task of downloading files in each host. I have a host file which looks like so

```
[groupa]
10.0.1.20

[groupb]
10.0.1.21
```

below is my main_file.yml file

```
---
  - hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: no
    roles:
      - oracle
      - apache
```

Structure of my roles

```
main_file.yml
roles
|-- oracle
|   |-- tasks
|       |-- main.yml
|       |-- download_file.yml
|-- apache
|   |-- tasks
|       |-- main.yml
|       |-- download_file.yml
```

oracle/main.yml

```
---
- name: downloading a file in groupa
  hosts: groupa
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/download_file.yml
```

oracle/download_file.yml

```
---
- name: download file
  shell: wget http://dummyurl.com/random.sh
```

Same steps are followed for Apache role but for "groupb". But when I execute main_file.yml I am getting the below error

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/oracle/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: downloading a file
  ^ here
```

Comment: Your main.yml doesn't have a debug statement as shown. Can you include the whole thing?

Comment: I get the same error even if I just do a debug task without adding any host in oracle/main.yml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ansible there are two levels, one is the playbook level, the other one is the task level. On the playbook level you can specify which hosts you want to run the tasks on, but under the tasks level this is no longer possible, as the hosts have already been specified. Roles are included at the tasks level, so you cannot have hosts declarations inside them.

You should remove the hosts from your main.yml, and only have the include:

```
---
- name: downloading a file in groupa
  include: download_file.yml
```

As roles are basically templates for a specific host, if you want them to run on a specific host just include them in your playbook accordingly. For example in your `main_file.yml` you can write the following:

```
---
- hosts: groupa
  roles:
    - oracle

- hosts: groupb
  roles:
    - apache

- hosts: local
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - { debug: { msg: "Tasks to run locally" } }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But I want each role to run on different host, is that possible?

Comment: @SztupY using this ansible will consider the first two host part as duplicate and use last defined value only .

Comment: how about delegate_to option ?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about executing roles on  hosts different from those specified in a playbook, but you can execute tasks on different hosts

an example.
the playbook specifies to execute tasks on app_servers group hosts.
however the task inside executes on db_servers group

---

```
- name: play 1
  hosts: app_servers

  tasks:
     - name: task 1
       mysql_db:
          name:  rails
          state: present
       delegate_to: db_servers
```